# How to read string separated by / with scanf

Tags: c, file, input, scanf

I`ve been trying to this for quite a while now and after some research I had no success, so my last resort was asking a question. My input looks like this:

```
1.0.0.0/255.0.0.0/127.0.0.1/1112 
1.2.0.0/255.255.0.0/2.4.6.9/1112
1.2.3.0/255.255.255.0/1.2.3.1/111
```

I need to extract 4 strings from each line, so for exemple the first line would give me

```
s1 = 1.0.0.0
s2 = 255.0.0.0
s3 = 127.0.0.1
s4 = 1112
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
scanf("%s/%s/%s/%s", str1, str2, str3, str4); // This doesn't consume the "/"
scanf("%[^/]s%[^/]s%[^/]s%[^/]s", str1, str2, str3, str4); // This only gets the first string
scanf(""%[^\n]s%*c%s%*c%s%*c%s", str1, str2, str3, str4); // Hera %*c was supposed to consume the "/" and do not store it, it doen't happen tho
```

How can I get the 4 strings from each input line using a single `scanf` inside a `while (!feof(fileIn))` ? Thank you.

Comment: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong)

Comment: The first doesn't consume the `'/'` because `%s` format reads up to the next whitespace character, so the `'/'` characters have already been read. Use `fgets` and break up the string with `strtok` or similar. The second stalls, as it would with `\n` because that was not removed. Note too, the string format is either `%[]` or `%s` but not the newbie hybrid of both which you have as `%[]s`.

Comment: Replace the `s`

Comment: @WeatherVane But can it be done with a single scanf? Even if it is "noob" to do so, I don't want unnecessary lines.

Comment: Write as many lines as you need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues with the posted code. The scanset directive is `%[]`; there is no `s` in this. The format strings using `%[^/]s` are attempting to match a literal `s` in the input. But this will always fail because `%[^/]` matches any character except for `/`. When a `/` is encountered, the match fails and the `/` character is left in the input stream. It is this character which must be consumed before continuing on to the next input field.

Also, [note that `while(!feof(file)){}` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Instead, try fetching input by lines using `fgets()`, and parsing with `sscanf()`. The `fgets()` function returns a null pointer when end-of-file is reached.

Further, you should always specify a maximum width when reading strings with `scanf()` family functions to avoid buffer overflow.

Here is an example program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char input[4096];
    char str1[100];
    char str2[100];
    char str3[100];
    char str4[100];

    while (fgets(input, sizeof input, stdin)) {
        sscanf(input, " %99[^/]/ %99[^/]/ %99[^/]/ %99[^/]",
               str1, str2, str3, str4);

        puts(str1);
        puts(str2);
        puts(str3);
        puts(str4);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample interaction using sample input from the question:

```
λ> ./a.out < readstring_test.txt 
1.0.0.0
255.0.0.0
127.0.0.1
1112 

1.2.0.0
255.255.0.0
2.4.6.9
1112

1.2.3.0
255.255.255.0
1.2.3.1
111
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You already got quite close: you missed to consume the delimiter in your second approach:

```
scanf("%[^/]/%[^/]/%[^/]/%[^/]", str1, str2, str3, str4);
```

should do the job.

Comment: `%[^/]s` is not the format you imagine it to be. It wants to match an `'s'` from the input. The string format is either `%[]` or `%s`. So it does not consume the `'/'` delimiter, which remains in the input.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this did not work, it only got the first string, the other 3 remained blank.

Comment: Sorry, I missed to remove the 's' characters. Try again, please.